# invoke a local application from a website and pass some parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services

I have a website which needs to execute a little application in local computer of visitors (They have windows 7). I will install this application in their computers.

Website after invoking this application, needs to pass some arguments like name, phone... to the application in order to print them.

The solution I have found is using internet explorer and ActiveXObject. Name, number ... will be passed as arguments.

But I'm not sure if the user is from China and writes his/her name in Chinese Characters Website through ActiveXObject will be able to send it to the application as argument.

This solution also prevents me to use google chrome or other browsers. I have found that I can do the same with Mozilla FF but not sure if I can do it in google Chrome (website user experience is better).

I have read about NPAP of google chrome, but I think appliction has to be written in C or C++, mine is in C#. ¿Can somebody confirm it?

So I'm interested in passing foreign characters to this application and a way to implement it in google chrome. Application can be invoked (passing the info as parameters) or using a webservice to comunicate with this application.  Application when finishes printing has to close browser and restart it (My website will be stablished as a default page).

Comment: Invoking a local application from a website is not a good idea. I don't know your specific constraints but from a top down view this does not seem like a good approach. ><

Comment: You might be better served to just create a print-friendly page with the stuff you need on it.  Pretty much all browsers can print, these days, and you can make print-specific css.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably registering your application as protocol handler when it installs and use links with this protocol on your pages (think how e-mail clients serve mailto: or torrent clients serve magnet: links). Since you control both sending and receiving side, you can pass pretty much any information in those. You can find Windows example for registering a handle at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Should you need it for any other system, I'm pretty sure searching for "system_or_gui_name register protocol handler" will show you desired result among the first.

Comment: Awesome idea - +1 for not hitting the concrete wall when you saw ActiveX.